# JWT Token is always received as expired while parsing

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am using JWT Authentictaion in one of my application along with Spring Boot/Security and its my first take on JWT.

Following are my set and get authentication methods:

```
static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, JWTPayload payload) {
    // all authentication related data like authorities and permissions can be 
    // embed to the token in a map using setClaims()
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    claims.put("roles", payload.getRoles());
    claims.put("permissions", payload.getPermissions());
    String JWT = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(payload.getUsername())
        .setClaims(claims)
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATIONTIME))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET_KEY)
        .compact();
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + " " + JWT);
  }


  /**
   * this method retrives the token from the header and validates it.
   * this method is called from the JWTAuthentication filter which is
   * used against all the incoming calls except the login.
   * @param request
   * @return
   */
  static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
      // parse the token.
      String user = Jwts.parser()
          .setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY)
          .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
          .getBody()
          .getSubject();

      return user != null ?
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) :
          null;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The JWT is generated and received in headers just fine. However, if used in subsequent API call, I receive following error.

```
io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2018-10-31T16:06:05Z. Current time: 2018-10-31T16:06:08Z, a difference of 3421 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
```

The exception says allowed clock skew is 0 milliseconds. In my above code `EXPIRATIONTIME` is set to 30000 (I believe this is set in seconds). I have tried increasing this value too but I still get the error.

Please suggest what am  I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have already got an answer, but someone might benefit from this some time. I had the same problem initially and I thought it was an issue with JWT. But, when I debugged my code, got to know that I was doing a silly mistake and the expiration date was set in the past.

So, for testing this I have created a sample program that you can execute standalone. Check this and modify your code accordingly. Hope this helps.

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jws;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

public class TestJWTToken {
    private static final String API_KEY = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String jwt = createJWT();
        System.out.println("JWT: " + jwt);
        parseJWT(jwt);
    }

    private static String createJWT() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
        cal1.setTime(cal.getTime());
        cal1.add(Calendar.SECOND, 300);

        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(API_KEY);
        Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, SignatureAlgorithm.HS256.getJcaName());

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("alg", "HS256");
        map.put("typ", "JWT");

        String someId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        return Jwts.builder().setHeader(map).setIssuer("service_provider").setSubject("consumer_provider_connectivity_token")
                .claim("some_id", someId).setIssuedAt(cal.getTime()).setExpiration(cal1.getTime())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, signingKey).compact();
    }

    private static void parseJWT(String jwt) {
        Jws<Claims> jwsClaims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(API_KEY)).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
        System.out.println("JWT decoded: " + jwsClaims);

        Claims claims = jwsClaims.getBody();
        System.out.println("Subject: " + claims.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Issuer: " + claims.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Issued at: " + claims.getIssuedAt());
        System.out.println("Expiration: " + claims.getExpiration());
        System.out.println("Some_Id: " + claims.get("some_id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and it didn't fix the issue. I see you have used Calendar API to fix the date rather than adding to the milliseconds. Was there any other specific change you wanted to mention.

Comment: You are assuming `EXPIRATIONTIME` is set in seconds, but as per your code, you are creating Date with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which is using the milli seconds and not seconds. So, when you are adding `EXPIRATIONTIME` to `System.currentTimeMillis()`, its treated as milliseconds and not as seconds. I have tried with your code and the JWT generated with your code is valid for 30 seconds, which is correct according to your code. If you want to set it for 30000, then you have to set `EXPIRATIONTIME` to 30000000